# Fatal error: Call to undefined function socket_create()

Tags: php

My code is like this:

```
if( ($this->master=socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP)) < 0 )

    {
    die("socket_create() failed, reason: ".socket_strerror($this->master));
    }
```

when I run my php file which create connection with web socket, I got error 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function socket_create() in the line 
if( ($this->master=socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP)) < 0 )

Therefore i am not able to connect web socket and also not able to get response message from socket because Socket Status: 3 (Closed) is displaying in my browser when run client page .

Have you got an idea what is missing?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: is sockets enabled in your configuration?

Comment: Do you have the extension enabled in your php.ini? (check phpinfo()).

Comment: Yes socket support enabled and browser is also support for web socket.

Comment: On official docker images just do `docker-php-ext-install sockets`

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You'll need to install (or enable) the [Socket PHP extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.sockets.php): http://www.php.net/manual/en/sockets.installation.php

Comment: I just had to uncomment it in my php.ini; I also had to copy it from another directory to the PHP directory, but it came with the installation.

Comment: Thanks Bob. i am using wamp server. First i changed in apache's php.ini and no effect. Then, i also changed in php's php.ini. At the end, websocket server started. :)

Comment: I have enabled `socket` extension in both php.ini but it still giving me same error. Do you guys have any idea why this would happen?

Answer (score 40):

For a typical XAMPP install on windows you probably have the php_sockets.dll in your C:\xampp\php\ext directory. All you got to do is go to php.ini in the C:\xampp\php directory and change the `;extension=php_sockets.dll` to `extension=php_sockets.dll`.

Comment: The only php.ini in my directory was php.ini-production  and php.ini-development, and I could not find ;extension=php_sockets.dll anywhere in those files, so I jjust wrote the line extension=php_sockets.dll in both and saved. I'm still getting the undefined function socket_create() error though, any idea? I'm using windows.

Comment: @2316354654 make sure your php.ini contains this lines`extension_dir="C:\xampp\php\ext" `

Comment: in my case `;extension=php_sockets.dll` was missing. I added it and now its working

Answer (score 12):

If you are using xampp 7.3.9. socket already installed. You can check xampp\php\ext and you will get the php_socket.dll. if you get it go to your xampp control panel open php.ini file and remove (;) from **extension=sockets.**

Answer (score 5):

Open the `php.ini` file in your server environment and remove `;` from `;extension=sockets`. if it's doesn't work, you have to download the `socket` extension for PHP and put it into `ext` directory in the php installation path. Restart your http server and everything should work.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps if you're on openSuse or SUSE.

Install php7 if it's not already installed.

```
zypper in php7
```

If you have php7 installed, update it with:

```
zypper update php7
```

Install php7-sockets

```
zypper in php7-sockets
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the version of your xampp (wamp or ...) is different with CLI. I suggest first using php --ini to find that use a correct version.

Moreover to solve this problem, you can open your xampp and use shell.

Answer (score -2):

I got this error when my `.env` file was not set up properly. Make sure you have a `.env` file with valid database login credentials.

Comment: this looks like a solution for at specific situation, and not  a general solution. .env files are not necessarily a standard for a php application...