# Minecraft Server Status using PHP

Tags: php, minecraft, server

I have a code snippet to query a Minecraft server and get all it's information, MOTD, Status, Online Players, etc.

I have grabbed the needed code from a GitHub repository and the example file. I edited the php file to the following:

```
include_once 'MinecraftServerStatus/status.class.php';
$status = new MinecraftServerStatus();
$response=$status->getStatus('185.38.148.138:25594', '1.7.*', 28028);
if(!$response) {
    echo"The Server is offline!";
} else {
    echo"<img width=\"64\" height=\"64\" src=\"".$response['favicon']."\" /> <br>
    The Server ".$response['hostname']." is running on ".$response['version']." and is online,
    currently are ".$response['players']." players online
    of a maximum of ".$response['maxplayers'].". The motd of the server is '".$response['motd']."'. 
    The server has a ping of ".$response['ping']." milliseconds.";
}


?>
```

The problem is when the php script was above the hello world text then it did not print anything, when it was below it ran the html but nothing came back from the php script.

I tried using the IP instead of the custom IP and nothing, I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

My server is online now, so trying to help would be amazing!

The links to the MCServerStatus code are here: [GitHub Link](https://github.com/mattvh/MCServerStatus)

And the link to my website: [The Page the PHP script is on](http://dannysmc.com/example.php)

The error is the following:`Fatal error: Call to undefined function socket_create() in /customers/c/5/1/dannysmc.com/httpd.www/MinecraftServerStatus/status.class.php on line 135`

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6137855/415324

Comment: Socket PHP extension is not enabled on your webserver. In order for that code to work, it needs to be enabled

Comment: The link you sent me I did not understand? How can I enable it on One.com's web server?

Comment: Nothing with the code. need to enable the Socket PHP Extension, or compile it in.

Comment: That's what I am saying how do I do this? I use One.com's web hosting? I don't understand that much and a little more explanation would be handy please

Comment: You have no controll over this. You can ask the one.com support, can they enable for you the socket php extension. I bet, their answer will no. So I think, you will need to find  a workaround for this.

Comment: Let me put it another way: one.com may not support the feature you need.  Contact them (believe they have livechat) to see if it's possible to enable it. The webpage example you gave us gave the error message that suggested the feature was disabled by one.com.

Comment: How can you create a work around as One don't support socket extension?