# Fatal error: Call to undefined function socket_create() and the normal fix doesn't work

Tags: php, websocket

And the "fix" that work for others but not me is to remove the ; from ";extension=sockets" in php.ini configuration file. Even when I restart XAMPP, apache server, even the whole computer it still doesn't work. Adding extension=php_sockets.dll doesn't work either. (I'm on windows 7 php version 8)

Comment: See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137823/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-socket-create#comment41069662_6137855). Have you edited the correct `.ini` file?

Comment: Are you certain that you've edited the correct php.ini file?  Sometimes there may be multiple versions, or the cgi version Apache is using may have a different ini file

Comment: Ok my PHP installation had two .ini folders, php.ini-development and php.ini-production. I found and undocumented the ; in ";extensions=sockets" and I still get the same error

Comment: Try writing `extension=php_sockets.dll` in the php.ini file that is in the apache folder (not only the one that's in the PHP folder). It's  a bit confusing, but do a search for "php.ini" in your entire XAMPP folder and you'll find it.

Comment: There is no such file in the appache folder, and after editing every single .ini, .ini-development and .ini-production file to include "extension sockets extension=php_sockets.dll" it still gives the same error