# API to access attendance data from the device

Tags: php

I have developed an ERP system for an educational institute using PHP & MYSQL. We have a thumb impression ZKTECO IN01-A device for the students' attendance. We want to fetch attendance data from the device automatically in the ERP system.

Can anyone please guide is there any PHP API to access attendance data from the  ZKTECO IN01-A device. I tried the file from https://github.com/nurkarim/zkteco-sdk-php which is giving  the following socket_create() error.

"Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function socket_create() in C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\zkteco-sdk-php-master\zklib\zklib.php:16 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\zkteco-sdk-php-master\zktest.php(10): ZKLib->__construct('192.168.10.1', 4370) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\erp\zkteco-sdk-php-master\zklib\zklib.php on line 16"

Any help or suggestions?

I would be humbly thankful.

Comment: Check if Socket Extension is enabled in PHP. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137823/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-socket-create

Comment: Please only use relevant tags for your questions!